# OpenACC: How to force copy data from host to device even if already present?

Tags: c++, gpu, openacc

I am trying to build some time metrics for an OpenACC code. One of the most time consuming tasks is copying a big array from the host to the device. I am running the same code multiple times in order to take an average and get a more accurate value. However, I ran into the problem that this big array is only copied once, therefore in all the subsequent runs of the code, the copying time is not taken into consideration.

I must be missing something here, but I thought that when we are working with 'structured data directives' the memory only exists within the data region. However, judging from my time measurements, this doesn't seem to be case. More insight on what is actually happening here would be greatly appreciated.

This is how the code looks like: (`data` is the big array that I want to explicitly copy into the device each time this is run)

```
#pragma acc data copyin(data[0:N*4]) create(grid[0:n*n], cell_ij) copyout(grid[0:n*n])
{
    // ...
}
```

I am compiling with:

```
pgc++ -lstdc++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 -acc -ta=nvidia -Minfo=accel
```

The compiler tells me:

```
Generating copyin(data[:262144]) [if not already present]
```

How do I get rid of the `[if not already present]`? Like copy it anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that these variables are not in another data region, they wouldn't be present so would be copied.  But if you want to be sure, you can use "create" in the data region and then use the "update" directive to explicitly copy the arrays.

```
#pragma acc data create(data[0:N*4], grid[0:n*n], cell_ij)
{
  #pragma acc update device(data[0:N*4]) 
    // ...
  #pragma acc update self(grid[0:n*n])
}
```